# Запись ответов в текстовый файл php

Tags: php, post

подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно добавить в коде, чтобы в результате анкетирования ответы записывались в текстовый файл?

```js
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['eduform']) && 
    isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['courses'])) 
{
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
    $secondname = htmlentities($_POST['secondname']);
    $eduform = htmlentities($_POST['eduform']);
    $hostel = "нет";
    if(isset($_POST['hostel'])) $hostel = "да";
    $comment = htmlentities($_POST['text']);
    $courses = $_POST['courses'];
    $output ="
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Анкетные данные</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    body{
    background: #C5D2DB;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

container{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
 </style>
    <body>
    <container>
    Вас зовут: $name<br />
    Ваша фамилия: $secondname<br />
    Форма обучения: $eduform<br />
    Требуется общежитие: $hostel<br />
    Ваш комментарий: $comment<br />
    Выбранный факультет:
    <ul>";
    foreach($courses as $item)
        $output.="<li>" . htmlentities($item) . "</li>";
    $output.="</ul></container></body></html>";
    echo $output;
}
else
{   
    echo "Введенные данные некорректны";
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>punkt_2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <h2>Анкета первокурсника</h2>
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
<p>Введите имя:<br> 
<input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<p>Введите фамилию:<br> 
<input type="text" name="secondname" /></p>
<p>Форма обучения: <br> 
<input type="radio" name="eduform" value="очно"/>очно <br>
<input type="radio" name="eduform" value="заочно"/>заочно </p>
<p>Требуется общежитие:<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="hostel" />Да</p>
<p>Выберите факультет: <br>
<select name="courses[]" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Факультет экономической информатики">ЭИ</option>
    <option value="Факультет экономики и права">ЭП</option>
    <option value="Факультет менеджмента и маркетинга">МиМ</option>
    <option value="Факультет международных экономических отношений">МЭО</option>
    <option value="Факультет консалтинга и международного бизнеса">КиМБ</option>
    <option value="Финансовый факультет">ФФ</option>
    <option value="ФАКУЛЬТЕТ подготовки иностранных граждан">ФПИГ</option>
</select></p>
<p>Краткий комментарий: <br>
<textarea name="comment" maxlength="200"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброе утро.

Используйте [file_put_contents();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php) Не забывайте о правах на запись для файла.

```
foreach($courses as $item){
    $output.="<li>" . htmlentities($item) . "</li>";
    $output.="</ul></container></body></html>";
    echo $output;
}
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output);
```

p.s. Хотя Ваш весь код надо переписать. Но если это первые шаги, то...

Answer (score -1):

Я не уверен что txt самое то, но вот как вариант для csv

Еще для записи нужно будет добавить права то есть

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data someFile`

Ну или создать отдельную папку чтобы не назначать полностью права на всю текущую папку или же создать группу

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['eduform']) && 
    isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['courses'])) 
{
    $hostel = "нет";
    if(isset($_POST['hostel'])) $hostel = "да";
    $comment = isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : 'комментария нету';

    $filename = 'tes.csv';

    $file_exist_bool = file_exists($filename); 
    // проверка на наличия файла в последующем два раза будет использоваться

    $method = 'w'; // опредяляем метод записи

    if( $file_exist_bool ) 
        $method = 'a+'; // в случае если файл существует, метод дозавписи в файл

    $file = fopen($filename, $method);

    if( !$file_exist_bool ) 
        fputcsv($file, array('firstname', 'secondname', 'eduform', 'hostel', 'text', 'courses'));
        // если файла нету, то записать header csv файла

    $data = array(
        array(  
            $_POST['firstname'], 
            $_POST['secondname'], 
            $_POST['eduform'], 
            $_POST['hostel'], 
            $comment, implode("&", $_POST['courses']) // здесь разбил так, как нужен string, 
            // то есть можно выбрать несколько факультетов 
            // по вопросу неправильно, но это уже сам сиправляй 
        )
    );

    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($file, $row);
        // сама запись
    }

    fclose($file);


}
else
{   
    echo "Введенные данные некорректны";
}
```

И как результат будет

```
firstname,secondname,eduform,hostel,text,courses
Имя,Фамилия,очно,on,"комментария нету","Факультет экономики и права"
```

А дальше пользуешься как xml, редактируешь, смотришь